# Is this sentence correct? How can I convey its meaning better?

Tags: complex-sentences

"There are 8000 clauses in Yili corpus with 5000 clauses as training corpus and 2000 clauses as testing corpus, and there are 6000 clauses in Zuozhuan corpus with 4000 clauses as training corpus and 2000 clauses as testing corpus."

Comment: yes it makes sense. If you want to make it slightly clearer: **"There are 8000 clauses in Yili corpus with 5000 clauses being training corpus and 2000 clauses being testing corpus, and there are 6000 clauses in Zuozhuan corpus with 4000 clauses being training corpus and 2000 clauses being testing corpus."** I just replaced "as" with "being"

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct.

I know some people really dislike parentheses in sentences, but I would shorten it as follows:

> There are 8000 clauses in Yili corpus (5000 training and 2000 test) and 6000 clauses in Zuozhuan corpus (4000 training and 2000 testing).

It gets the same idea across, with fewer repeated elements.  In my opinion, it also is easier for the eye to syntax properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use parentheses (which I personally like using), you can use "of which" instead of repeating the word "clauses":

"There are 8000 clauses in the Yili corpus, 5000 of which are for training and 2000 for testing, and 6000 clauses in the Zuozhuan corpus, 4000 of which are for training 2000 for testing."

I also believe "Yili" and "Zuozhuan" should be preceded by "the".

Finally, depending on where you are located, you may want to add a comma separator in your numbers: in the United Kingdom and the United States, commas are usually used every three decimals for numbers greater than one thousand. Other countries (such as most European countries and, increasingly, Canada) follow the International System of Units  and use spaces to separate groups of thousands for numbers greater than ten thousand.

Here is an excerpt from the [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI):](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf)

" 10.5.3 Grouping digits

Because the comma is widely used as the decimal marker outside the United States, it should not be used to separate digits into groups of three. Instead, digits should be separated into groups of three, counting from the decimal marker towards the left and right, by the use of a thin, fixed space. However, this practice is not usually followed for numbers having only four digits on either side of the decimal marker except when uniformity in a table is desired.

Examples: 76 483 522 but not: 76,483,522

43 279.168 29 but not: 43,279.168 29

8012 or 8 012 but not: 8,012

0.491 722 3 is highly preferred to: 0.4917223

0.5947 or 0.594 7 but not: 0.59 47

8012.5947 or 8 012.594 7 but not: 8 012.5947 or 8012.594 7

Note: The practice of using a space to group digits is not usually followed in certain specialized applications, such as engineering drawings and financial statements."